# Godot C# get/set variable in another script attached to another object

Tags: c#, object, godot

In **Godot 3.5.1** and **C#** from a **script "SA.cs"** attached to an **object OA**, I wish **get/set** a **string variable U** that lays in another **script "SB.cs"** attached to another **object OB**. Both object OA and OB are attached to the same Spatial Node. Can someone write how to code this? (- other examples out there are not working or missing details).

Comment: When I add this script to Object OA:

Node ob = GetNode("/root/Spatial/OB");
SB sb = (SB)ob.GetNode("SB");
GD.Print("U in OB: "+sb.U);  

Godot crashes. Can someone help with this? Thanks

Comment: You can edit your question to add information.

Answer (score 0):

> Both object OA and OB are attached to the same Spatial Node.

If I understand correctly, OA and OB are siblings, children of an Spatial Node. So the scene tree looks like this:

```
Spatial
├ OA
└ OB
```

*Note that I'm not using the word "attached" to refer to the relationship between `Node`s.*

It is against general advice, but let us do it anyway…

Form OA:

- `GetNode(".")` is OA.
- `GetNode("..")` is Spatial.
- `GetNode("../OB")` is OB.
- `GetNode("root")` is the scene tree root.
- `GetNode("/root/Spatial")` might or might not be Spatial. It is Spatial if Spatial is the root of the scene, and this scene is the current scene.
- `GetNode("/root/Spatial/OB")` might or might not be OB. Depending if `GetNode("/root/Spatial")` is Spatial or not.

---

From your description SB is a script that is attached to OB, not a Node. So doing the following makes no sense:

```
SB sb = (SB)ob.GetNode("SB");
```

If `SB` is the class from the script attached to OB, then you do this:

```
SB sb = (SB)ob;
```

*Note that I'm using the word "attached" to refer to the relationship between a `Script` and a `Node`.*

Or directly do this:

```
var sb = GetNode<SB>("../OB");
```